# spring.transaction.default-timeout property is not working in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, microservices, spring-transactions

I am building a microservice  and using MYSQL as database and Spring boot framework. I have provided my database properties in application.properties and "spring.transaction.default-timeout=10" in property file. I don't have explicitly initialized the datasource and entitymanager. Using that which is auto configured by spring.

Now problem is below -:

Some of my transactions remain in blocking state due to lock acquired by other transaction on database table. I want to cancel transaction if wait time exceeds more than 10 sec. I have configured the property as mentioned above. But it is not working for me.

Note -: I have explicitly initialized the datasource and entitymanager and JtaPlatfromtransaction manager. But still not working for me.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have configured the `PlatformTransactionManager` yourself, the property will have no effect. You'll need to call `setDefaultTimeout(int)` yourself if you're configuring the transaction manager manually.

Comment: I am setting default timeout as setDefaultTimeout(10) but not working.

Comment: If you're using `JtaPlatformTransactionManager` the timeout maps down to a call to `UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(timeout)`. Exactly how that behaves will depend on the underlying JTA implementation that you're using and MySQL. It [appears](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32005) that MySQL may not support the timeout that you're hoping for.

Comment: MYSQL default timeout of 50 sec is working but spring timeout is not working. I have tried all the ways.